# Android Picasso gives mixing versions error

Tags: android, picasso

I`m getting an error due to mixing versions

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). 
>   Found versions 28.0.0-rc01, 27.1.0. Examples include 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-rc01' and 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'

The `com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0` is coming under Picasso,
maybe with Picasso, since I added version 28, yet Picasso still using version 27, and Volley is using version 28:

```
+--- com.android.volley:volley:1.1.+ -> 1.1.1
+--- com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
\--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
 +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0
 |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0
 +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0 -> 28.0.0
 \--- com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)


dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

How to fix this issue, should I downgrade the SDK to 27? or use Glide?

Thanks,

Comment: Use: 28.0.0 version which is the stable version first. Then use: [`2.71828` for the Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). If it didn't solve the issue, add `implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'` to your dependencies.

Comment: No, it's not the same issue. I did what you suggest, but still the same.
    `+--- com.android.volley:volley:1.1.+ -> 1.1.1
+--- com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0
\--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
     +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0
     |    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0
     +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0 -> 28.0.0
     \--- com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0 -> 28.0.0 (*)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try it:

```
implementation ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: ['exifinterface', 'support-annotations']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix will be adding the match version for the libraries which has this issue(Like I said).

But now, change the dependencies as follows:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0' // Like this
```

Or you can try to override `com.android.support:support-annotations` to v `28.0.0` too.

If this didn't help, since I've checked and picasso [is updated to 28.0.0](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/build.gradle#L10) support library, then perhaps the libraries it uses is still using `27.1.0`.

So you can downgrade to `27.1.0`, or use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

<sub>I don't want to judge the libraries but with the new versions, I prefer the Glide one which has better documentation even for Kotlin and using snapshots for the new APIs. So consider this as the last choice or, simply add the latest version and use it.</sub>